# Change fill on circle, within an SVG, within an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

So I chose to create an object to put an SVG object into, because I want to replicate it 100 times or more. Here is the SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="ballsvg" viewBox="0 0 98 98">
    <g>
        <circle class="changeCircle" cx="50%" cy="51%" r="48%" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="blue" />
        <text class="changeText" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="65%" font-family="Verdana" font-size="30" fill="white" ><tspan>0</tspan>  </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

And my JavaScript that builds out the objects to the div `#svgMain`:

```
for(var i=0; i<addingTo; i++){
   var obj = '<div class="clickBall" data-id="'+String(i+1+totalBalls)+'" ><object class="ball" data="ball.svg"></object></div>' 
   appendHTMLNodes += obj;
}
```

Then I found online how to dynamically change the text on that object:

```
$( "object.ball" ).each(function( index ) {
    var textNode = $(this.contentDocument);
    textNode = textNode.find(".changeText");
    textNode = textNode.children().first();
    textNode.text(index+1);
});
```

Then I wanted to change the fill color when the item is clicked:

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickBall', function(event) {
    var mySVG = $(this).find("object.ball");
    mySVG = $(mySVG.contentDocument);
    mySVG = mySVG.find(".changeCircle");
    console.log(mySVG);
    mySVG.attr("fill", "#FF0000");
});
```

But I cannot figure out how to get the right element, because it never changes the  fill, even though I could change the text before.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Where is `object.ball` in the markup?  You should be able to set fill through css: `mySVG.css("fill", "#FF0000");`

Comment: And `.clickBall` too

Comment: The object is created on the fly, it references data="ball.svg". ClickBall is a div that encompasses the object tag. <div clickBall><object><svg><circle> in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly select the `.changeCircle` and use `$(this)` property to fill `svg`. Try this code:

```js
$(".changeCircle").on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({ fill: "#ff0000" });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="ballsvg" viewBox="0 0 98 98">
    <g>
        <circle class="changeCircle" cx="50%" cy="51%" r="48%" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="blue" />
        <text class="changeText" text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y="65%" font-family="Verdana" font-size="30" fill="white" ><tspan>0</tspan>  </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**UPDATE:**

[tcoulson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/715699/tcoulson) wanted to update SVG inside a `object` tag. Here is how you can access SVG `object`:

```
$(function(){ 
    $("#obj").contents().find(".changeCircle").attr({"fill":"lime"}); 
    console.log($("#obj").contents().find(".changeCircle")); 
});
```

Comment: I have reasons for adding the other layers - mostly because I wanted to have a data id that I could access in order to track which button was clicked. I suppose I could add a data attribute to the circle. Let me look at restructuring this.

Comment: You want to track button click? I thought you are here because `I cannot figure out how to get the right element, because it never changes the fill`

Comment: Your code sample is too simplistic, it is not loading or referencing the changeCircle within an svg, within an object tag. I have to have the object tag to duplicate the elements 100 times.

Comment: Enclosing SVG's in `object` tag and giving them id to reference differently is also possible. Is this what you want? Or you are willing to load SVG's from CDN or something? Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4p5dren8/1/) if you are willing to put SVG's directly into html.

Comment: This is one of my first times using svg's on a project. I started to learn more about them. Decided to load them with img tag. Then found out I can access the info in them with object tag. I have not heard of the cdn option yet.

Comment: CDN(content delivery network) is a place where you keep your cached html files, your images, etc. But in your case, you are using `SVG`s and don't require huge huge bandwidth to transfer and hence causes less load on server. You can put your `SVG`s in `object` tag, give them `id` or `class` and write functions for them.

Comment: I am kind of doing that currently, this is a small localhost project, don't need to display it online. I am creating an object with jquery, linking in my external file, and duplicating it 100 times, then I am changing the text and trying to change the button on click. It is weird I am calling console.log($(".ballsvg")), but I am only getting back "[prevObject: r.fn.init[1]]" it doesn't look like it is getting all of the svn items on the stage.

Comment: Have you tried this `console.log($("#svgID .ballsvg"));`? This should work just fine. I have updated the fiddle, please check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/4p5dren8/2/) link.

Comment: It is not working because of contentDocument, but I cannot make the right call. Your fiddle didn't replicate my problem, because the svg was not loaded into the object tag with the data attribute. So mine is acting like a innerHtml, but I cannot figure out how to call to inside that linked item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127918/discussion-between-aniket-sahrawat-and-tcoulson).